# module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'load'

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

`image = Image.load(img)`

This line gives me the error. I was trying to load an image.
`AttributeError: module 'PIL.Image' has no attribute 'load'`

Comment: [`Image.load()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.load) loads associated pixel data, is something you do *after* opening an `Image`.

Answer (score 0):

Do this instead:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open("path_to_image.png")
```

Replace "path_to_image" with your actual path.

Please read the docs: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to get pixel access object, you have to:

```
img = Image.open("path/to/image")
img.load()
```

2. It's not nessessary to use `.load` method, because the Image class automatically loads an opened image when it is accessed for the first time.